# TortoiseSVN reverter a uma versão anterior

Tags: tortoisesvn

Tanho um código e estou usando o controle de versão Tortoise. Iniciei da versão 1 e agora estou na versão 10. Mas percebi que tenho um problema e preciso voltar o meu código para a revisão 6.

Vou nas propriedades e solicito para reverter para tal revisão. Até ai tudo bem.

Mas a partir desse ponto, eu gostaria de utilizar esse ponto do código para continuar a programar. Chamar essa revisão 6 de 11 e continuar a partir dela. Porém quando tento dar um commit recebo uma mensagem de erro, que minha versão do código não está atualiza e eu preciso atualizar ela primeiro (ou seja atualizar para a versão 10). Mas o que eu quero é justamente não atualizar ela, para não utilizar as partes que eu quero descartar.

Como então, enviar o nova versão do código para o servidor?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Faça um *branch* desta versão 6. Dê um nome fácil de identificar;
2. Faça suas modificações no *branch*, realize *commit*;
3. Se assim desejar, volte para o *trunk* e faça um *merge* vindo do seu *branch*.

Pode ser necessário mais algumas modificações manuais e resoluções de conflitos.

Comment: Para concluir. Se eu usar a opção "revert to this revision" quando tempo para retornar para uma revisão mais antiga, ele não permite que eu faça o "commit". Para funcionar eu preciso selecionar todas as revisões que quero descartar simultaneamente, e marcar um "revert changes from these revisions". Ai sim eu consigo dar um novo "commit" baseado em uma revisão antiga.

Comment: @AntonioRafaeldaSilvaFilho Sim, isso acontece porque o SVN trabalha de maneira incremental. Apenas revertendo uma revisão cria-se um problema de consistência entre os arquivos. Isto ocorre porque o SVN não guarda os arquivos inteiros, e sim porções modificadas que são usadas para remontar o arquivo no momento em que você realiza um Checkout ou um Update.